# how can i add a right click menu to finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, finder

how can i add a custom view to the right click menu of every file in os x finder?

e.g. i want to display the image if it is an image type and do some custom action etc.

is this possible with c or objective-c? if yes how? (without using any available  tool)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write a [Menu Manager](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/reference/Menu_Manager/Reference/reference.html) plugin based on CFPlugin. Unfortunately, this involves some really dated Carbon stuff. There is a tutorial from a few years ago at [mactech](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.18/18.08/MenuPlugins/index.html)

Note that this stuff may be obsolete with Snow Leopard, though whatever they come up with is probably going to be much easier to deal with than Menu Manager/CFPlugin cruft.

Comment: Also, you can't insert a custom view this way. Text only.

Comment: I'll just answer my own question. As stated in the original answer, this is obsolete as of Snow Leopard. Unfortunately, they have NOT replaced it with something easier. You can implement "services" menu items, but that only gets you part of the way there.